# Twitter style URLs in asp.net application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter

I am working on one application it's like twitter.
So how can I accomplish the url such as,

```
twitter.com/username
```

This will open profile related to username.

I am creating using asp.net.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using MVC Razor, it will be as simple as passing a query string parameter to your page. For example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
     //Get user information and pass to view
     User userDetails = SomeLogic.GetUser(name);

     return View(userDetails);
}
```

Or, if using ASP.NET Web Forms you will have to use Friendly URL's by adding a Nuget package. Tutorial can be found here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/southasiamvp/archive/2014/03/31/guest-post-exploring-asp-net-friendlyurls.aspx

In the grand scheme of things, all you need to do is pass a query string parameter to your page. Using the friendly URL's will help you accomplish the URL format you require.

## Update

From your comment, I see you are using Web Forms, so I will modify the answer on getting a query string value. The code below won't render URL in a friendly format, but I am hoping you will then be able to modify the example based on the link I provided above.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.QueryString["name"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["name"].ToString())
   {
       string myNameValue = Request.QueryString["name"].ToString();

       //Since you have the name in the querystring, pass value to method that retrieves the record
       User userDetails = SomeLogic.GetUser(name);
   }
}
```

So the URL will be: profile.com/profile.aspx?name=John.

But as I stated, you will need to modify the code to change the example to use Friendly URL's, that can be found in this tutorial: http://blogs.technet.com/b/southasiamvp/archive/2014/03/31/guest-post-exploring-asp-net-friendlyurls.aspx

Comment: I want user to send request like this profile.com/john and john info opens up on profile.aspx. the info comes from db

Comment: @abc I have updated my code sample, but I suggest you look at database tutorials, such as Entity Framework that will show you how to get data back from the database. For example: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx & http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application. Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not like profile.com/name=john. It's like profile.com/john

Comment: @abc I understand that. I gave that as an example to ensure you understood how to utilise querystring parameters. I have given you a link to a good tutorial (in my post) on how to achieve profile.com/john. Read through that. Here is an additional URL that you will find helpful: http://www.devcurry.com/2013/05/friendly-urls-in-aspnet-web-forms.html. Read the "Query String Parameters and Friendly URLs" section. You have been given the tools, now have a go writing some code and if you have further issues, update your post.